# What is the relation between BRST quantization and gauge fixing quantization

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory

To quantize gauge field, one usually use gauge-fixing procedure and then plus ghost field, my question is what the relation between BRST quantization and gauge fixing quantization is? Because the latter is a special case of the former. Thanks!